# How to have same vertical weight between group of components in Constraint Layout Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I am usin Constraint layout . What i want is to have same  vetical weight(width) between group1 and group2, and group2 and end of screen.In linear layout i would put one group to vertical linear layout and group2 same to vertical linear layout and put that two layouts in parrent vertical layout and set weight to 1. But how to do that in constraint layout?

Here is sample picture:
[image]

So what i want is to have same width space between group1 and group2 and group2 and end of screen.

Like this:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constrait"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minHeight="47dp"
app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="4"
tools:context="example.com.constrait.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="24dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_edittext"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText6" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText8"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_edittext"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView8"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />
```

Comment: You are talking about vertical weigh and width so I am not sure to understand your question. Are you looking for both group to have the same height or for components in both groups to have all the same size?

Comment: Check my update please for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `Chains`.

You can look at this [blogpost](https://medium.com/@nomanr/constraintlayout-chains-4f3b58ea15bb) where I took the following snippets from.

Basically you want to chain together your widgets like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View 1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View 2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/view3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View 3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And for your specific use case, you might want to use

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle=”spread”
```

Comment: app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle=”spread”, Where to add this property?

Comment: On each widget inside the constraint layout that are chained together.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code as per the need test this code and see if it works for you:-

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView15"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView16"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView11"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView17"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView15"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView16"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText12"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText13"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText12"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText13"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText14"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText12"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText12" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText14"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText13"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText13" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView21"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView22"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView22"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView23"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView21"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView21" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView23"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView25"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView22"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView22" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView25"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView23"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView23" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText15"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText16"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView21" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText16"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText17"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText15"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText15" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText17"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText18"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText16"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText15" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText18"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText17"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText15" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have edited layout as per the need. Take a look now. Add edit text background as per your need.

Comment: It looks same as mine xml

Comment: Updated the answer. check now.